# Discord.js loadstring

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

I want to make a command for a bot to evaluate a string (run it as code). Is there a way to **run a *string*** as code in discord.js? Not rly having a code sample here, I just want to know of a function to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

discord.js is using Node which uses Javascript, so your solution to evalute a code from a string should be with the `eval()` method.
[Eval on developer.mozilla.org](http://%20https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

However, as soon as you implement `eval()`, you'll soon find out that they have access to basically your whole computer. I would not recommend you to use this.

Comment: This command is gonna be bot owner only so it's not like my PC is on sale 0$.